# FindFragmentByTag restricted to specific container

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with two Fragment containers (R.id.first_column_container and R.id.second_column_container).

I'm using a fragment that can go in either containers (only one instance per container) and I need to access either one or the other.
As of now I'm using this method:

```
public static Fragment getFragmentByTag(FragmentActivity act, String tag) {
    return act.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

But when, as an example, I have an instance on both column and I need to access some method only on the second one I can't.

Is there a way to combine findFragmentById(containerId) and findFragmentByTag(tag), to make a findFragmentByTag(containerId, tag), that would search only between fragments in the specified container?

As of now the only solution I see is to use a different tag for each container, but I would avoid that.